# Making XSLT for XML to XML simple transform

Tags: xml, xslt

I have such XML document:

```
<?xml version=”1.0”?>
<root>
    <sub>
        <value>1</value>
    </sub>
    <sub>
        <value>2</value>
    </sub>
    <sub>
        <value>3</value>
    </sub>
</root>
```

I want to transfer into other XML:

```
<?xml version=”1.0”?>
<entries>
    <sub value="1">
    <sub value="2">
    <sub value="3">
</entries>
```

What XSLT document will realize such a transformation?

Comment: As you say yourself, this is simple - so why do need to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic XSLT question. The requirements are:

1. Generate entries element from root element.
2. Generate sub element with @value attribute that have string value of the value element.

The code is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <entries>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </entries>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sub">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="string(value)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```